# Inherit Top Link Bar While Creating Sub Site using JavaScript object module

Tags: top-link-bar

Is it possible to use the call `SP.Navigation.set_useShared(true)` to inherit the top link bar in the javascript to create a sub site?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, are you talking about inheriting the top navigation or creating a sub site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `sp.publishing.js`

```
var webNavSettings = new SP.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings(context, currentWeb);
var navigation = webNavSettings.get_globalNavigation(); 
navigation.set_source(3);     
webNavSettings.update();         
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){   alert("Navigation Modification Successful");         },function(sender,args){       alert(args.get_message());       });
```